# Theads in a pool gets into blocked state when pool fills up

Tags: java, multithreading, blocking, executorservice

I have an application that has a threadpool size of 20 and whenever all the threads in the pool is exhausted the threads get into blocked state forever essentially browning out the application. The application works fine when the pool is partially filled. Thread dump shows that the threads were blocked in running an async callable, and there isnt any stack info regarding where the callable is at though. What should i be looking at to figure out why the threads get into blocked state whenever the pool fills up.

The dump also says no deadlock was detected.
I use executor service for thread management.

Threaddump:

```
Thread 25903: (state = BLOCKED)
 - sun.misc.Unsafe.park(boolean, long) @bci=0 (Compiled frame; information may be imprecise)
 - java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(java.lang.Object) @bci=14, line=186 (Compiled frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await() @bci=42, line=2043 (Compiled frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take() @bci=29, line=442 (Compiled frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask() @bci=156, line=1068 (Compiled frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker) @bci=26, line=1130 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run() @bci=5, line=615 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.lang.Thread.run() @bci=11, line=745 (Interpreted frame)

Thread 25889: (state = BLOCKED)
 - java.lang.Object.wait(long) @bci=0 (Compiled frame; information may be imprecise)
 - com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread.run() @bci=34, line=534 (Compiled frame)

Thread 25888: (state = BLOCKED)
 - java.lang.Object.wait(long) @bci=0 (Compiled frame; information may be imprecise)
 - java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop() @bci=201, line=552 (Compiled frame)
 - java.util.TimerThread.run() @bci=1, line=505 (Interpreted frame)

Thread 25857: (state = BLOCKED)
 - sun.misc.Unsafe.park(boolean, long) @bci=0 (Compiled frame; information may be imprecise)
 - java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(java.lang.Object) @bci=14, line=186 (Compiled frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.awaitDone(boolean, long) @bci=165, line=425 (Compiled frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get() @bci=13, line=187 (Interpreted frame)
 - dummy1.dummy2.dummy3.ValueLoaderFactory$Builder.build() @bci=16, line=271 (Interpreted frame)
```

Comment: Have you tried using a profiler? Yourkit works pretty well.

Answer (score 0):

`ValueLoaderFactory$Builder.build()` seems to wait on other threads so the current thread can't continue. Essentially this removes one thread from to pool. If several threads do this the pool gets empty very quickly.

**Update**

Look on line 271 of ValueLoaderFactory to see what the threads is waiting for. Possibly your issue is something like this

- Task A submits Task B to the thread pool, gets a `Future` back, waits on the future
- Task B submits Task C to the thread pool, gets a `Future` back, waits on the future

At this point you have two threads in the pool blocked waiting for other threads. If your thread pool size is bigger than 2 everything will still complete because there is a thread in the pool available for Task C.
However if you thread pool size is 2 then at this point nothing will happen anymore. Because there is no thread available in the pool for Task C. Therefore Task B forever blocks a thread in the pool because it waits for Task C to execute which will never happen. Same goes for Task A with will forever happen for Task B.

Comment: there were 20 threads stuck at "ValueLoaderFactory$Builder.build()".

Comment: There's your problem.

Comment: the problem is im not sure what it is waiting on, based on the dump they are waiting on Future.get(). Im not sure why they get blocked forever only when the entire pool is exhausted else the threads are processing fine.

Comment: @broun what should result of completed `get()`? Perhaps, there's limited resource, shared across your threads, which, when exhausted, causes endless waiting? Perhaps, your threads forget to free such resource, once it's not needed?